# How to clear contents of a row based on if the date listed in a cell in that row has already passed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet for inventory, where columns A-D list the position in the warehouse and metadata related to that position, and columns E-G list the item in that position, the date that it was placed there, and the date that it is set to be removed, respectively. I am trying to write a script that will automatically clear the contents of columns E-G (but leave columns A-D untouched) in any row for which the date in column G has already passed (i.e. that item has been removed from that position in the warehouse, and is now empty again).

My initial thought was to set conditional formatting, to highlight the cells for which the date has already passed in orange, and then write a script to clear all orange cells and set it to trigger on a daily basis. I am very new to this, so I took this script from someone I found online https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/79924/clear-range-of-cells

```
function clearOrange() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Blad1');
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var bgColors = range.getBackgrounds();
  for (var i=0; i<bgColors.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<bgColors[i].length; j++) {
      if (bgColors[i][j] === '#ff9900') {
        range.getCell(i+1,j+1).clearContent();
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

When I went to set the conditional formatting, I found that I needed to set a rule for every single row (for example "highlight E2:G2 if G2 is before today" would have to be a separate rule from "highlight E3:G3 if G3 is before today") and I did not want to spend the time to write thousands of conditional formatting rules. Does anyone have any thoughts on how I can get this script to recognize when the date in the row has passed, without me having to do the conditional formatting?

Comment: Did you try to modify the script?  Have you taken a basic tutorial at JavaScript?

Comment: Your assumptions on the conditional formatting are false; it would be easiest for you to google how to set up the conditional formatting correctly (e.g., the custom formula required)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Summary

- You have a column with dates `G`
- You want to compare the dates in the column with the current date
  +You want to delete the rows in the columns `E` to `G` for all dates which lie in the past

### Solution

- You do need to manually highlight cells in orange
- Instead, you can directly compare the dates to the day of today
- You can implement the conditional statement for date comparison within a loop that iterates through all rows

**Here a sample of what the corrsponding function could look like:**

```
function clearPastDates() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Blad1');  //name to be replaced with the actual name of your sheet
  var firstRow=2;
  var lastRow=sheet.getDataRange().getLastRow();
  var firstColumn=5;
  var lastColumn=7;
  //set up here you range to be cleared
  var range = sheet.getRange(firstRow,firstColumn,lastRow-firstRow+1, lastColumn-firstColumn+1); 
  // get the values in your date column
  var dateValues=sheet.getRange(firstRow,lastColumn,lastRow-firstRow+1).getValues() 
  var today=new Date(); //get the date from today
  //loop through all rows
  for (var i=0; i<dateValues.length; i++) {
 //compare today's date to the date in the dateValues column
      if (today>=dateValues[i][0]) {  
    //if date in dateValues lies in the past, delete all cells in the respective row within range 
        for(var j=0; j<range.getValues()[0].length; j++){
         range.getCell(i+1, j+1).clearContent();
        }
    }
  }  
}
```

If you want to run the function on time trigger, you can do by going from the Apps Script UI to `Edit > Current project's triggers->Add new one`. Please refer to this tutorial for more information.

### Other related references:

[Working with ranges](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)

[Working with dates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)